# Описание переменной цикла for

Tags: c++, c

Очевидно, что все пишут так:

```
for(int i =0; i < 5;i++){
   //...
}
```

Но встретил мнение, что такая конструкция абсолютно неправильна и является лишь происками разработчиков компиляторов. Соответственно, надо так:

```
int i=0;
for(;i < 5;i++){
   //...
}
```

Что в действительности «правильно» по стандарту?

Comment: Оба варианта правильные. Единственное отличие заключается в доступности переменной `i` после окончания цикла.

Comment: **Очевидно** - нет.

Comment: Самая правильная конструкция -- *do { } while ()*, всё остальное лишь синтаксический сахар.

Comment: Осталось спросить, что правильно в цикле - `i++` или `++i`...

Comment: @0andriy а Страуструп говорит не использовать `do ... while`…

Comment: Страуструп не знал различие между NULL и 0 долгое время, можем ли мы доверять Страуструпу?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Язык си вплоть до версии C99 не позволяет объявлять переменные в выражении инициализации цикла **for**. То есть в выражении до первой точки с запятой между круглыми скобками после `for (...)`. Кроме того, в языке си версии ниже C99 запрещены однострочные комментарии, начинающиеся с двух наклонных чёрточек (слешей), имеются только многострочные `/* ... */`.

Таким образом, оба ваших примера кода являются верными с точки зрения С (но начиная с версии С99 и выше), а также в C++ (любой версии).

Но тем не менее, эти кусочки немного различаются семантически. В первом случае после окончания цикла вы не сможете получить доступ к его счётчику — переменной `i`, так как она объявляется в области видимости цикла. Во втором случае после окончания цикла `i` будет равно 5 (если не будет инструкций перехода). И переменную можно будет использовать далее, например, что-нибудь присвоить ей. Однако не стоит этим заниматься — это считается признаком плохого стиля, и первый вариант предпочтительнее.

Comment: Кто конкретно считает такой стиль плохим? Вообще, все зависит от алгоритма. Если `i` используется *только* в цикле, то ее лучше объявлять внутри `for(;;)`. Если же по смыслу задачи (алгоритма) она нужна и после цикла (например, он может завершаться по `break` (или т.п.)), ничего ужасного в таком ее использовании (а значит и объявлении до `for(;;)`) нет.

Comment: если уж совсем правильным быть, использование цикла в коде вполне может быть признаком плохого кода (для C++), поскольку очень многие задачи решаются через стандартную библиотеку алгоритмами

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, выбор первого или второго варианта как в С++, так и в современном С, делается на основе того, необходимо ли вам продлить область видимости переменной `i` за пределы цикла. Поэтому вне контекста ни первый, ни второй вариант в общем случае не могут рассматриваться как однозначно предпочтительные. Вопрос в том, что именно вам нужно в данном месте кода.

Во-вторых, заголовок цикла `for` допускает только одну декларацию. Это означает, что если у вас процесс итерации обслуживается несколькими переменными, требующими разных *decl-specifier-seq*, то хочешь-не хочешь, но некоторые из них придется объявить перед циклом

```
unsigned i = 0;
for (double *it = container; i < n; ++i, ++it)
  ...
```

Это ограничение можно обойти способами вроде

```
for (struct { unsigned i; double *it; } i = { 0, container }; i.i < n; ++i.i, ++i.it)
  ...
```

но как правило оно того не стоит.